# Writing a wrapper that uses FFI when on MRI and Java when on JRuby

Tags: ruby, interop, jruby, ffi

I need to wrap a new library for use by Ruby. The plan was to detect which implementation of Ruby is in use, and load a C library via FFI if on MRI, and wrap a Java lib if using JRuby.

I'm having trouble finding docs, so any pointer would be helpful. I know there are other libraries that do this, but I can't find one at the moment, so if you know of any gem that does this that would also be helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start, you can inspect the value of the `RUBY_ENGINE` constant at runtime.

Running under MRI (1.9.x), it'll be "ruby". Under JRuby, "jruby".